# How to use an integer list to find rows in pd.DataFrame with non-integer indices

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

How can I make this work?

```
import pandas as pd

L = [1,3,5]
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], index=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7])

print(df[0])
print(df[0].loc(L))
```

I would like to have this output format:

```
0.2    2
0.4    4
0.6    6
```

Comment: Are you sure the output you have provided is correct? For the given output integers should be list L = [1,4,6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is `.iloc`

```
df.iloc[L]
Out[477]: 
     0
0.2  2
0.4  4
0.6  6
```